# how to split emoji unicode strings in python

Tags: python, unicode, split

I'm receiving emojies from a chat application and i want to separate each single emoji when there are multiple emojies. I'm able to catch a single emoji as an unicode value.but split function does't work for multiple emoji unicode values.This code is for a single emoji

```
def getEmoji(data)
    sleepy_face = [u'\U0001F6CC', u'\U0001F634', u'\U0001F4A4']

    if (data in sleepy_face):
        return emoji.emojize('Are you sleepy? :slightly_smiling_face:', use_aliases=True)
```

I tried this to separate multiple emojies

```
encode_data=data.encode('raw_unicode_escape')
find_data = encode_data.split(b'\\\\')
for extract_data in find_data:
    print(extract_data)
    if (extract_data in sleepy_face):
        return emoji.emojize('Are you sleepy? :slightly_smiling_face:', use_aliases=True)
```

Split method returns again encode_data. How can i solve this?

Comment: Is it possible to use NLTK tweetNLP for a same result?

Comment: Seems like in Python they are prepended with a 'u' 

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f634/index.htm

Perhaps that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
data = u'\U0001f6cc\U0001f634\U0001f4a4'
for i in re.findall(ur'..', data):
    print i
    if i in sleepy_face:
        return
```

when run:

```
re.findall(ur'.', data)
```

you will get:

```
[u'\ud83d', u'\udecc', u'\ud83d', u'\ude34', u'\ud83d', u'\udca4']
```

**3 emojies == 6 unicode chars**.

Another way:

```
s =  u'\U0001F6CCabc\U0001F634bcd\U0001F4A4'
for i in re.findall(ur'([\ud000-\udfff][\ud000-\udfff])', s): 
    # change range '\ud000'-'\udfff'
    print i
```

thx @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams.
Edit:
if Python with UCS-4:

```
for i in re.findall(".", data):
    if i in sleepy_face:
        print i
```

Comment: Only if you're using a UCS-2 build of Python.

Comment: thx @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams. if UCS-4(or python3), 1 emojie = 1 unicode char.